How to identify differences in polars dataframe when assert_series_equal / assert_frame_equal fails?
I am using pl.testing.assert_frame_equal to compare two pl.DataFrames. The assertion fails. The traceback indicates that there are exact value mismatches in a certain column.
The column in question is of type bool. It also contains null values. This column has more than 20,000 rows and I need to figure out, where exactly the difference is.
What I did is to create a mask that shows a true value whenever there is a difference between the actual dataframe and the expectation dataframe.
mask = actual != expectation

What I then noticed is that the mask only contains false and null values in every column.
mask.sum().sum_horizontal() gives 0.
That means this is apparently not a good way to identify the rows with differences.
In my large dataframe I expect a situation like the following:
import polars as pl
from polars.testing import assert_frame_equal

df1 = pl.DataFrame(
    {
        "group": ["A", "A", "A", "B", "B"], 
        "value": [True, False, None, False, None]
    }
)
df2 = pl.DataFrame(
    {
        "group": ["A", "A", "A", "B", "B"], 
        "value": [True, False, False, False, None]
    }
)

Performing assert_frame_equal(df1, df2) will correctly result in an AssertionError.
AssertionError: DataFrames are different (value mismatch for column 'value')
[left]:  [True, False, None, False, None]
[right]: [True, False, False, False, None]

The inequality test doesn't help in order to identify where the differences is as there are no true values.
df1 != df2

shape: (5, 2)
┌───────┬───────┐
│ group ┆ value │
│ ---   ┆ ---   │
│ bool  ┆ bool  │
╞═══════╪═══════╡
│ false ┆ false │
│ false ┆ false │
│ false ┆ null  │
│ false ┆ false │
│ false ┆ null  │
└───────┴───────┘


A [mre] would be nice - see How to make good reproducible pandas examples. Unless the problem is so puzzling that even that's not possible.

If you look at the implementation:

asserts/frame.py#L14
asserts/series.py#L151

It is using .ne_missing() to compare the values.
df1.select(df1[col].ne_missing(df2[col]) for col in df1.columns)

shape: (5, 2)
┌───────┬───────┐
│ group ┆ value │
│ ---   ┆ ---   │
│ bool  ┆ bool  │
╞═══════╪═══════╡
│ false ┆ false │
│ false ┆ false │
│ false ┆ true  │
│ false ┆ false │
│ false ┆ false │
└───────┴───────┘

(As well as the schema / dtype validation, etc.)

When you add with_row_index, it becomes even easier to visually inspect the differences: df1.select(df1[col].ne_missing(df2[col]) for col in df1.columns).with_row_index

Correct: df1.select(df1[col].ne_missing(df2[col]) for col in df1.columns).with_row_index()

You could do something like this to find differences between dataFrames:
pl.concat([
    df1.join(df2, on=["group","value"], join_nulls=True, how="anti"),
    df2.join(df1, on=["group","value"], join_nulls=True, how="anti")
])

Apparently it doesn't work fully how I would expect it to work, though, second join doesn't return anything, I think it's a bug in Polars.
This was the answer before details were added to the question.
I think the confusion comes from SQL-compliant null comparison of polars.
Here's an example:
actual = pl.DataFrame({
    "a": [None, True],
    "b": [False, None]
})

expectation = pl.DataFrame({
    "a": [True, True],
    "b": [False, False]
})

shape: (2, 2)
┌──────┬───────┐
│ a    ┆ b     │
│ ---  ┆ ---   │
│ bool ┆ bool  │
╞══════╪═══════╡
│ null ┆ false │
│ true ┆ null  │
└──────┴───────┘
shape: (2, 2)
┌──────┬───────┐
│ a    ┆ b     │
│ ---  ┆ ---   │
│ bool ┆ bool  │
╞══════╪═══════╡
│ true ┆ false │
│ true ┆ false │
└──────┴───────┘

You see, these dataframes are not equal.
But if you create a mask as you did:
mask = actual != expectation

Then you'll see that nulls compared with any value will still give you null
shape: (2, 2)
┌───────┬───────┐
│ a     ┆ b     │
│ ---   ┆ ---   │
│ bool  ┆ bool  │
╞═══════╪═══════╡
│ null  ┆ false │
│ false ┆ null  │
└───────┴───────┘

And that, in turn, will be count as 0 for sum() and sum_horizontal():
mask.sum().sum_horizontal()

shape: (1,)
sum
u32
0

So there's no mismatch between these methods.

I realized the same fact and edited my question. Now, what's the best way to proceed from here in order to identify where the exact mismatches are?

One possible route is to fill the null values with true values. Then the mask becomes useful. Subsequently, adding a row index to the mask further helps to identify the differences. Having said all that, I am wondering if there exist a more pythonic way?

@Andi I edited the answer accordingly. Logically, anti-join with join on nulls should work both ways, but for some reason it only works one way. I need to look into it further and probably file a bug if it's not there yet

@Andi filling mask with true might not work as you expected, if you have null in both dataframes then df1 != df2 will havenull as a result.

I meant to fill the null values in actual and expectation with true values before creating the mask.

@Andi that would work if you don't need to distinguish between null and true
